PowerShell ANSI escape sequences crash the shell if sequence string is too long
Can anyone shed any light on why executing the first statement does what's expected and returns to the prompt but the second one, while completing what's expected, crashes PowerShell 5 and 7 a few seconds after? I've tried "press any key" code and while it does show the "press any key" prompt, the shell still crashes.
This is about using ANSI escape sequences in PowerShell to colour top and bottom parts of a character in order to render a simple bitmap in the console. I'll need at least 20 columns X 20 lines to render without crashing the shell.
PowerShell statement that does not crash the shell:
"$([char]27)[38;2;222;234;241;48;2;7;103;172m$([char]9600)$([char]27)[38;2;148;186;213;48;2;1;99;168m$([char]9600)$([char]27)[38;2;222;234;241;48;2;7;103;172m$([char]9600)"
Output:

PowerShell statement that crashes the shell (the same statement that doesn't crash the shell, repeated):
"$([char]27)[38;2;222;234;241;48;2;7;103;172m$([char]9600)$([char]27)[38;2;148;186;213;48;2;1;99;168m$([char]9600)$([char]27)[38;2;222;234;241;48;2;7;103;172m$([char]9600)";"$([char]27)[38;2;222;234;241;48;2;7;103;172m$([char]9600)$([char]27)[38;2;148;186;213;48;2;1;99;168m$([char]9600)$([char]27)[38;2;222;234;241;48;2;7;103;172m$([char]9600)"
Output:

I have these PowerShell versions installed and computer admin rights ($PSVersionTable):
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.4170
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.4170
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.4.3
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.4.3
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0

UPDATE:
This happens in PowerShell running via Windows Terminal 1.20.11381.0.
There are no entries in the Application Event Log for the crash.
UPDATE 2:
Cortex XDR has intercepted the PowerShell commands but didn't bother to display any messages about that. It appears that too long a string of escape sequences triggers a "script obfuscation heuristic" rule.

I'm unable to reproduce the described behavior in either version of PowerShell, in both Windows Terminal and the Console Host... can you elaborate on the crash itself - does the window just suddenly close unexpectedly after a few seconds? Does it show any error messages/stack traces beforehand? Do you see any errors in the Application or System channels in the Event Log?

@Mathias R. Jessen PowerShell suddenly closes 3-5 seconds after completing the request. There are no error messages.

@Mathias R. Jessen I've updated the question with more information.

I guess, an answer is needed for future searchers.
The problem with crashing PowerShell and Windows Terminal was caused by Palo Alto's Cortex XDR service intercepting calls, which had ANSI escape strings long enough to trigger "script obfuscation heuristics". For some reason, my local installation of Palo Alto's tools didn't display any messages at the time but has recorded the events that can be viewed once the Palo Alto console is opened.
The solution, albeit long winded, turned out to be defining all colours for the top and bottom of a character in one call, and only one at a time.
Something like this in a PowerShell script would work:
Write-Host -NoNewLine "$([char]27)[38;2;251;255;255;48;2;245;255;255m$([char]9600)";
Write-Host -NoNewLine "$([char]27)[38;2;251;255;255;48;2;244;255;255m$([char]9600)";
Write-Host -NoNewLine "$([char]27)[38;2;242;255;255;48;2;206;244;255m$([char]9600)";
Write-Host -NoNewLine "$([char]27)[38;2;221;255;255;48;2;85;144;174m$([char]9600)";
Write-Host -NoNewLine "$([char]27)[38;2;141;204;235;48;2;44;122;161m$([char]9600)";
Write-Host -NoNewLine "$([char]27)[38;2;77;156;195;48;2;35;122;167m$([char]9600)";
Write-Host -NoNewLine "$([char]27)[38;2;56;140;184;48;2;33;124;168m$([char]9600)";
Write-Host -NoNewLine "$([char]27)[38;2;59;142;184;48;2;32;123;167m$([char]9600)";
Write-Host -NoNewLine "$([char]27)[38;2;95;169;208;48;2;35;122;167m$([char]9600)";
Write-Host -NoNewLine "$([char]27)[38;2;172;227;255;48;2;47;119;157m$([char]9600)";
Write-Host -NoNewLine "$([char]27)[0m";
Write-Host "";

